# xcodebuild: error: 'project.pbxproj' is not a project file

Tags: xcode8

I am new to Xcode so I am probably doing something wrong (or missing something in this case). I would appreciate any help.

I've just created a new project on Xcode. New Project -> macOS -> Command Prompt. I've saved it somewhere and as soon as Xcode returns with its main screen on my project's properties, I've closed it. Then cd'd to the folder where my .xcodeproject was (on terminal) and ran `xcodebuild install` and it returns me that message. Additionally, I tried editing my project Schema from `debug` to `release` and closed Xcode again (to make sure everything was saved), same error.

If I build the project from Xcode's UI it works, obviously, it will print Hello World, but I can't run the builder from command line. Does anyone have any tips? Thank you!

This is on Xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: Can you show a listing of your file directory? The `pbxproj` file is a configuration file of sorts that keeps your Xcode project in order.

Comment: Sure. Just the Xcode created files, I haven't even edited main.swift. https://pastebin.com/QRyzhsbQ

Comment: By the way, I am running that command from inside the .xcodeproj directory, where the pbxproj file is.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue and my error was due to an overlooked flag in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Pretty easy fix :)

So the error says:

> `xcodebuild: error: '<some file>' is not a project file`.

The reason for that was because in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file it said `-project` instead of `-workspace`

Super easy to overlook. So if you have the: `is not a project file` error, make sure your flag says `-workspace` and not `-project`.

Alternatively if you have the opposite error  `xcodebuild: error: '<some file>' is not a workspace file` then you'll want to change your `-workspace` flag to `-project`

---

Comment: Thanks so much! This is such a silly mistake, so when I searched for it, there were little to none results. So thanks for this! It really helped me!!

Comment: Wow! hahaha I just posted this. That was fast @ShashaHaven !

It's always a pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

My bad... the `xcodebuild install` command works from one directory up, outside the .xcodeproj folder.